# iTunes keeps crashing - malloc_history possible for iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes

So I have a problem with iTunes crashing every time I try to activate iTunes Match.

After talking about 3 Hours with Apple they said I should just reinstall OSX.
Great. So I went looking into the problem on my own.

It seems that iTunes is trying to free an allocated object that couldn't been allocated before so iTunes crashed.

iTunes(2407,0x10e2f5000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd20ab694c0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Is it possible to activate malloc logging for iTunes?

I want to use malloc_history to search for the problem..

Comment: Well, it happens to me too on Microsoft Vista:
"iTunes has stopped working" the first time I started iTunes Match.
When trying it a second time it just hangs. I uninstalled everything apple from my notebook, rebooted, installed, same thing. So I don't think it's an OSX issue either. If I were you I'd continue to nag the iTunes people about it.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it's possible to use malloc or not, this is definitely not a normal thing, so the problem is elsewhere. It certainly doesn't happen to millions of customers out there. The OS Reinstall will probably fix it, but before going that crazy, I'd try to do the usual Mac maintenance stuff.

One trick that usually helps me a lot is to create a blank new user and try from there. If it works, then you can start digging "what is in my account that breaks this?"

Starting in Single-User also helps to diagnose stuff.

TL;DR: something is broken, malloc won't help you much. Start with the basic.

On the other hand, you *might* have a RAM problem.